# Delete a zip file after unzip in java

Tags: java, delete-file

How to delete a zip file in java?  file.delete method returns false. Why?

```
File file = new File("/mibook/"+mFilename+"/"+mZipname.toString());
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

edit:
Rule "Directory should empty before deletion.." does it apply for zip file?

My file unzipping code

```
   public void unzip() throws IOException { 
        FileInputStream fin=null;
        ZipInputStream zin=null;
        File file =null;
        ZipEntry ze ;
        FileOutputStream fout=null;
        try{ 
            System.out.println(_zipFile );
            System.out.println(_location);
            fin = new FileInputStream(_zipFile); 
            zin = new ZipInputStream(fin); 
            ze= null; 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((ze = zin.getNextEntry()) != null) { 
                file = new File((_location +"/" + ze.getName()));
                file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                 fout= new FileOutputStream(_location + ze.getName()); 
                while ((length = zin.read(buffer))>0) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                zin.closeEntry(); 
                fout.close();

            }
            zin.close(); 
        }catch(Exception e) { 
            Log.e("Decompress", "unzip", e); 
        }

        finally {
```

```
            fin.close();
            zin.close();
            fout.close();


    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have used.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE (http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Given that the problem code downloads a Zip, you might use the basicservice.zip file at my site (http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#bs) it is small at around 3Kb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `file.delete()` returns false, then my guess is that another process has the zip file open - or possibly even your own process.

- Check that you've got the path correct, e.g. what does `file.exists()` return?
- Check that you've got permission to delete the file as the user running your application
- Check that you haven't got an open handle to the file within your code (e.g. have you just read from it and not closed the input stream?)
- Check that you don't have the file opened in a desktop app

Comment: @jon in my code i just download a zip file and unzip into some other location after that im try to delete zip file. any condition is violated  ? if so hw can i recover from that?

Comment: Assuming you did all of that in Java, the most likely problem is that your code still has the ZipStream open.

Comment: @vnshetty: I agree with Stephen. I suspect you've failed to close a stream somewhere. We can't tell without seeing your code though.

Comment: @vnshetty: Well for one thing, you should be putting `close` statements in `finally` blocks so the handles get closed even if there's an exception. But you've also not shown where you're closing `zin` itself. Basically you've shown a *portion* of your unzipping code, but not all of it.

Comment: @jon edited my quest again. and Rule "Directory should empty before deletion.." does it apply for zip file? and i checked with file.exists() returns true.

Comment: @vnshetty: Now you've shown *another* stream - `fin` - which you're not closing. I don't know whether `ZipInputStream.close` will close `fin` for you, but it would be a good idea to close it anyway IMO. And you're still not using `finally` blocks. If there are any exceptions (which you're just swallowing after logging, and indiscriminately at that) you won't be able to delete the file. But no, you don't need to somehow "empty" a zip file before deleting it.

Comment: @vnshetty: I'm glad, but for completeness each of your `close` methods should be in its own finally block (or use something like Guava's `closeQuietly` method). Otherwise if one close method throws an exception, the other streams won't be closed.

Answer (score 9):

You have to make sure you close your ZipFile.

For example I had:

```
ZipFile zFile = new ZipFile("blah");
//lots-o-code
zFile.close();
File file = new File("blah");
file.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very common when attempting to delete a file that you've created. Be sure to `close` the FileWriter you used to create the unzipped file.

If you can't figure out where to close the file, your best bet may be to call `file.deleteOnExit()` which should succeed even if you accidentally leave a few file handles open.

Answer (score 0):

Use : `FileUtils.delete(yourFile);`

This corrected my problem